# GMail Add-On / Apps script can't connect to Google Cloud SQL - permission to call getCloudSqlConnection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql, gmail-addons

I'm writing a simple add-on that will get sender's data for each message from our DB. 
GMail add-on gets the message-id and queries our DB for additional data about the client to show it to the user.

I've followed CloudSQL tutorial, for MySQL and Postgres and in the simpliest scenario I'm getting this error

> You do not have permission to call `getCloudSqlConnection`

while I'm trying to connect to GCP Cloud SQL. No problem to connect from outside with external client, etc. though.

The code is as follows

```
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://[my-project-and-instance-id]/[my-db-name]", [user], [password]);
```

My script is attached to the same project as the database.

An internet search for "You do not have permission to call getCloudSqlConnection" gives an empty result.

Comment: You need to share the scopes you've defined for your add-on - odds are you didn't update them to include one that you need. Review the Google Identity Platform for the proper OAuth scope you need.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, my scopes are "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose"
  ],

Which scopes would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice" to "oauthScopes" in my manifest file fixed the error for me.

**Updated scopes:**

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose"]
```

Comment: consider adding more information in your answer, a link can be removed in future and the information contained in that can be lost consequently